# Как соединить сервер на node.js с использованием Socket.io с игрой на Unity3D (C#) через WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity3d, websocket, socket.io

Пытаюсь соединить сервер на node.js на котором используется WebSocket с игрой на Unity3D. Вся игра будет написана на C#, по этому соединение желательно сделать на нем же.

Код на сервере:

```
const express = require("express"),
    socketDriver = require("socket.io"),

    app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Request");
    res.status(200).jsonp({
        text: "Hi!!!!!!"
    });
});

const server = app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Server is starting!"));

const serverSocket = socketDriver(server);

serverSocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("client connected");

    socket.emit('on-login', "Hi, I am server.");
});
```

Код на клиенте:

```
void Start ()
{
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); 
    int port = 4000;  
    Socket Sock1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Sock1.Connect(ip, port);
}
```

Сервер не как не реагирует на попытку подключения (не печатает "client connected"). Клиент работает без ошибок.

Пытаюсь разобраться нашел много примеров, но все они не работают. Чувствую что что то делаю не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю вам стоит обратить внимание на библиотеку:
https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet